# Three.js Orbit Controls in Equirectangular mapped sphere - maintaining position

Tags: three.js, rotation

I have mapped an equirectangular image onto a sphere using `three.js`, placed the camera in the middle of the sphere, and am using the `OrbitControls` to handle things like zooming & rotation.

This all works fantastically until I want to programmatically adjust what the camera is looking at (I tween `camera.target`) which ends up changing, I believe, the position of the camera. The issue here is that afterwards when you rotate, you rotate out of the sphere. What would be the proper way to achieve this only by adjusting `camera.rotation` and `camera.zoom`. I'm okay with stripping down the `OrbitControls` but don't fully understand how the rotation should work and am also open to other optins.

Comment: Please do not change the question after it has been answered. Please restore the original question and make a new post if you need help.

Comment: Oops okay, let me do that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using `OrbitControls` in the center of a panorama, you should leave `controls.target` at the origin, and set the camera position close to the origin:

```
camera.position.set( 0, 0, 1 );
```

By setting

```
controls.enablePan = false;
controls.enableZoom = false;
```

the camera will always remain a distance of 1 from the origin, i.e., on the unit sphere.

Then, to look at `( x, y, z )`, you programmatically set the camera's position like so:

```
camera.position.set( x, y, z, ).normalize().negate();
```

That way, when the camera looks at the target (the origin), it will automatically be looking at `( x, y, z )`, too.

three.js r.85

Comment: Wow, @WestLangley I can't even tell you how much time I have spent on this! Thanks so much. One minor issue: The camera now swings all the way around as I tween it but I'd like it to just take the shortest path. I have updated my initial post with the tweening code.